# SQL Server 2008 change tracking and primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, primary-key, change-tracking

I needed to set `change tracking` in `sql server 2008` table to true but it gave an error that the table has to have a `primary key`

1. Is there a way to enable change tracking without setting a `primary key` in my table
2. Is it a good programming practice not to set `primary keys`? I am creating a system but i don't want to set them on `SQL` tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The Table must have primary key in order to enable Change tracking

Having primary keys on a table infarct is a good programming practice.
```

Comment: I have set the primary key on a table and enabled the change tracking. I modified `current_DateTime` but is giving an error `column does not allow nulls` yet it is null and i want it `not null`.

Comment: what is the datatype of current_datetime field?

Comment: I have set the `current_datetime` datatype as `datetime`...this field will capture the actual time a record is entered into the database like when recording a transaction

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Change Tracking on a table which has Primary key.
It is must. Because Change Tracking works based on Primary key in a table.

You can find some more additional information from my Article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/537649/SQL-Server-Change-Tracking-CT#_comments